# Cargo workspace with nested packages not working properly

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have the following project structure:

```
.
├── Cargo.toml
└── task1
    ├── Cargo.toml
    ├── src
    │   ├── main.rs
    │   ├── resources.rs
    │   └── users.rs
    └── tests
        └── task1.rs
```

./Cargo.toml:

```
[workspace]
members= ["task1"]
```

and ./task1/Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "task1"
version = "0.1.0"

[dependencies]
rand = "0.8.5"
```

where users.rs uses functions from rand: `use rand;`

Although I've structured this, following https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html, it seems the rand package is not being detected by users.rs anyways when I build (`` unresolved import `rand` `` ).

Not sure how to solve this, or if it's unsolvable what's the best workaround. I intend to have more packages besides task1 aswell.

Comment: How do you include `users.rs` in `task1`? What does `resources.rs` have anything to do with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't include the edition, it defaults to 2015. [Automatic `extern crate` was added in edition 2018.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/path-changes.html#no-more-extern-crate) You should always use the latest edition for new projects. Projects generated with `cargo new` or `cargo init` will always include the edition.

```ini
[package]
name = "task1"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
rand = "0.8.5"
```

Comment: That was it, thanks. Also had to add `resolver = "2"` in the root Cargo.toml.